# Maven project can not be created in Eclipse Neon using Archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, proxy

Maven project can not be created in Eclipse Neon using Archetype and i get the below error. (screen shots are attached)

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

proxy settings is correctly configured for maven. Also i could create maven projects using the command line without any issue.

I have tried almost every solutions recommended in the internet. but no luck. Now this issue is killing me.

[image]

Your help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Proxy / Firewall Issue...using internal repository manager?

Comment: i did not get you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are facing configurational issue. Go to settings.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

         <proxies>
            <proxy>
              <id>proxyname</id>
              <active>true</active>
              <protocol>http</protocol>
              <username>username</username>  
              <password>password</password>  
              <host>127.0.0.1</host>   
              <port>80</port>
              <nonProxyHosts>any.host</nonProxyHosts>
            </proxy>    
          </proxies> 
        </settings>
```

Make sure you are pointing to default proxy and given correct credentials.

Location reference for settings.xml: /repositories/buildtools/apache-maven-3.2.2-developer/conf/settings.xml

Reply me if further understanding is required.